# IPtables port forwarding to host machine IP

Tags: linux, networking, iptables, nat, wireguard

I have WireGuard installed in an LXC container and while the client connects normally (I see the port and the information), it doesn't connect when I try to `curl` to `localhost` [`127.0.0.1`] or its IP [`192.168.1.180`]:

```bash
# 10.7.0.2:6060 ⟷ 192.168.1.180:6060
  # Host IP:  192.168.1.180
  # IP:       10.7.0.2

# Resolves okay:
  curl -I 10.7.0.2:6060

# Response unreachable:
  curl -I 127.0.1:6060
  curl -I 192.168.1.180:6060
```

While the route should allow the below, I have responses from `10.7.0.2:6060` on `192.168.1.180`, but not from `127.0.0.1:6060` [unreachable]:

- `192.168.1.170`  → (`192.168.1.180:6060` [LXC] → `10.7.0.2:6060` [Network])

  - `192.168.1.170`: Network PC (gateway: 192.168.1.1)
  - `192.168.1.180`: LXC container VM
  - `10.7.0.2`:      WireGuard Client PC

  `ip route list`:

  ```bash
  default via 192.168.1.1 dev eth0 proto static
  10.7.0.0/24 dev wg0 proto kernel scope link src 10.7.0.1
  192.168.1.0/24 dev eth0 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.1.180
  ```

---

- IPv4 Forward is active:

  ```bash
  #sysctl net.ipv4.ip_forward
  net.ipv4.ip_forward = 1
  ```
- WireGuard config: `/etc/wireguard/wg0.conf`

  - Server: [`wiretest`]

    ```bash
    # ENDPOINT asd.demo.net
    [Interface]
    Address = 10.7.0.1/24
    PrivateKey = CI0heA/1InAo........
    ListenPort = 51820

    # BEGIN_PEER nodotest
    [Peer]
    PublicKey = y1t+k9cR06F7/y6ANJtEx.......
    PresharedKey = +Tya8VsxbB3i9hkIRf......
    AllowedIPs = 10.7.0.2/32
    # END_PEER nodotest
    ```
  - Client: [`wiredocker`]

    ```bash
    [Interface]
    Address = 10.0.0.2/24
    DNS = 8.8.8.8
    PrivateKey = +GLTuJnydedy2QMvTj5SGdr......

    [Peer]
    PublicKey = qlNPgT7Fwbjmexq09EVF........
    PresharedKey = +Tya8VsxbB3i9hkIR......
    AllowedIPs = 0.0.0.0/0, ::/0
    Endpoint = asd.demo.net:51820
    PersistentKeepalive = 25
    ```
- IP Tables:

  ```bash
  iptables              -A FORWARD      -i eth0                       -j ACCEPT
  iptables      -t nat  -A PREROUTING   -p tcp    --dport 6060:6060   -j DNAT --to-destination 10.7.0.2
  iptables  -w  -t nat  -A POSTROUTING  -o eth0                       -j MASQUERADE
  ```

  - `iptables -L`: (server)

    ```bash
    Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
    target  prot  opt   source        destination
    ACCEPT  udp   --    anywhere      anywhere        udp dpt:51823

    Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
    target  prot  opt   source        destination
    ACCEPT  all   --    anywhere      anywhere        state RELATED,ESTABLISHED
    ACCEPT  all   --    10.7.0.0/24   anywhere

    Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
    target  prot  opt   source        destination
    ```
  - `iptables-save`:

    ```bash
    # Generated by iptables-save v1.8.7 on Sat Jul 17 12:19:27 2021
    *filter
    :INPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
    :FORWARD ACCEPT [0:0]
    :OUTPUT ACCEPT [0:0]

    -A INPUT -p udp -m udp --dport 51823 -j ACCEPT
    -A FORWARD -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
    -A FORWARD -s 10.7.0.0/24 -j ACCEPT

    COMMIT
    # Completed on Sat Jul 17 12:19:27 2021

    # Generated by iptables-save v1.8.7 on Sat Jul 17 12:19:27 2021
    *nat
    :PREROUTING ACCEPT [0:0]
    :INPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
    :OUTPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
    :POSTROUTING ACCEPT [0:0]

    -A  PREROUTING  -i  eth0 -p tcp     -m tcp          --dport 6060  -j DNAT --to-destination 10.7.0.2:6060
    -A  PREROUTING  -i  eth0 -p tcp     -m tcp          --dport 1010  -j DNAT --to-destination 10.7.0.2:6060
    -A  PREROUTING  -i  eth0 -p tcp     -m tcp          --dport 1010  -j DNAT --to-destination 10.7.0.2:6060
    -A  POSTROUTING -s  10.7.0.0/24   ! -d 10.7.0.0/24                -j SNAT --to-source      192.168.1.183

    COMMIT
    # Completed on Sat Jul 17 12:19:27 2021
    ```

Comment: `PREROUTING` does not cover traffics from the host itself. If you want to do `DNAT` for those, also add a rule to `OUTPUT`.

Comment: Besides, I wonder why you `MASQUERADE` for `-o eth0` instead of `-o wg0`. Also `Address` in your client conf makes no sense either. (Maybe it isn't the conf you are actually using?)

Comment: @TomYan thank for you reply, i should replace PREROUTING for OUTPUT and  eth0 for wg0 ? in the server right ?

Comment: Depends on what you need. Since you mention all the forwarding stuff, I assume you want the server act as a router in this context. For traffics from hosts other than itself, you still need the same rule in `PREROUTING`. With the `AllowedIPs` in your client conf, whether you need `MASQUERADE` for `-o wg0` / at all depends on whether the clients LAN subnet(s) conflicts with the server's. I am not seeing why you need that for `-o eth0` base on what I see in your question. You haven't been clear on your exact setup / goal though.

Comment: i need that when i call 192.168.1.180:6060 that go to 10.7.0.2:6060 (over the wireguard vpn) , i habe resolve from 10.7.0.2:6060 but is not this link between 192.168.1.180 and 10.7.0.2 , with the wg0 and OUTPUT has no effect.

Comment: Again, "call" from where (which host)? Also please just update your questions with the output of `iptables-save`.

Comment: @TomYan  192.168.1.170 call the host 192.168.1.180:6060, in the host 192.168.1.180 i habe another network 10.7.0.2 were i need call the port 6060 . I write this in the post now :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/127602/discussion-between-tom-yan-and-victorelec14).

Comment: @TomYan Hi, i write you on chat